# Multi Celery projects with same RabbitMQ broker backend process

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

How can I use **two different celery project** which consumes messages from **single RabbitMQ installation**.

Generally, these scripts work fine if I use different rabbitmq for them. But on production machine, I need to share the same RabbitMQ backend for them.

Note: Due to some constraint, I cannot merge new projects in existing, so it will be two different project.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

RabbitMQ has the ability to create virtual message brokers called virtual
hosts or vhosts. Each one is essentially a mini-RabbitMQ server with its own queues. This lets you safely use one RabbitMQ server for multiple applications.

`rabbitmqctl add_vhost` command creates a vhost.

By default Celery uses the **/** default vhost:

> celery worker --broker=amqp://guest@localhost//

But you can use any custom vhost:

> celery worker --broker=amqp://guest@localhost/myvhost

**Examples**:

```
rabbitmqctl add_vhost new_host
rabbitmqctl add_vhost /another_host
```

> celery worker --broker=amqp://guest@localhost/new_host
>
> celery worker --broker=amqp://guest@localhost//another_host

Comment: Worked great. Before implementing this method, I was trying with different Queue/Exchange config, but that didn't worked. With different VHOST, there is no conflict and both Celery apps are working fine to me.